# Apache IMPALA - How to rewrite the query to fix the GROUP BY error

Tags: sql, impala

Hello I have a query and it produce the following error:

```
AnalysisException: select list expression not produced by aggregation output (missing from GROUP BY clause?): CASE WHEN unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(now(), 'Asia/Jerusalem')) > unix_timestamp(lat) THEN 'LAT Passed' ELSE substr(CAST(round((((unix_timestamp(from_utc_timestamp(now(), 'Asia/Jerusalem')) - unix_timestamp(eat)) / 60) / ((unix_timestamp(lat) - unix_timestamp(eat)) / 60)) * 100, 2) AS STRING), 1, 5) END EAT_to_LAT
```

The query looks like following and I know that the columns 'eat' and 'lat' are missing in the GROUP BY section, but I want to group the output only by the column 'delivery_slot_from':

```
  SELECT delivery_slot_from_hour
             AS delivery_slot_from,
         COUNT (order_line_id)
             AS order_lines,
         SUM (
             CASE
                 WHEN order_line_status IN
                          ('FINISHED', 'CANCELED', 'PICKED')
                 THEN
                     1
                 ELSE
                     0
             END)
             AS order_lines_finished,
         ROUND (
               (  SUM (
                      CASE
                          WHEN order_line_status IN
                                   ('FINISHED', 'CANCELED', 'PICKED')
                          THEN
                              1
                          ELSE
                              0
                      END)
                / COUNT (order_line_id))
             * 100,
             2)
             AS picking_lines_percent,
         CASE
             WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                      from_utc_timestamp (now (), 'MYRegion')) >
                  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (lat)
             THEN
                 'LAT Passed'
             ELSE
                 SUBSTR (
                     CAST (
                         ROUND (
                               (  (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                                            from_utc_timestamp (
                                                now (),
                                                'MYRegion'))
                                      - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                                   / 60)
                                / (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (lat)
                                      - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                                   / 60))
                             * 100,
                             2)
                             AS STRING),
                     1,
                     5)
         END
             AS EAT_to_LAT,
         ROUND (
               SUM (
                   CASE
                       WHEN order_line_status IN
                                ('FINISHED', 'CANCELED', 'PICKED')
                       THEN
                           1
                       ELSE
                           0
                   END)
             / COUNT (order_line_id)
             * (  (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                            from_utc_timestamp (now (),
                                                'MYRegion'))
                      - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                   / 60)
                / (  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP (lat) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                   / 60))
             * 100,
             2)
             ratio
    FROM my_table
   WHERE SUBSTR (delivery_slot_from, 1, 10) = '2023-06-28'
GROUP BY delivery_slot_from
ORDER BY delivery_slot_from;
```

I already tried something like this, but it also get me an error and I'm out of my knowledge now:

```
SELECT main.delivery_slot_from_hour    AS delivery_slot_from,
       main.order_lines,
       main.order_lines_finished,
       ROUND (
             (  main.order_lines_finished
              / main.order_lines)
           * 100,
           2)                          AS picking_lines_percent,
       CASE
           WHEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                    from_utc_timestamp (now (), 'MYRegion')) >
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP (MAX (lat))
           THEN
               'LAT Passed'
           ELSE
               SUBSTR (
                   CAST (
                       ROUND (
                             (  (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                                          from_utc_timestamp (
                                              now (),
                                              'MYRegion'))
                                    - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (main.eat))
                                 / 60)
                              / (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (main.lat)
                                    - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (main.eat))
                                 / 60))
                           * 100,
                           2)
                           AS STRING),
                   1,
                   5)
       END                             AS eat_to_lat,
       main.ratio
  FROM (  SELECT delivery_slot_from_hour,
                 eat,
                 lat,
                 COUNT (order_line_id)
                     AS order_lines,
                 SUM (
                     CASE
                         WHEN order_line_status IN
                                  ('FINISHED', 'CANCELED', 'PICKED')
                         THEN
                             1
                         ELSE
                             0
                     END)
                     AS order_lines_finished,
                   SUM (
                       CASE
                           WHEN order_line_status IN
                                    ('FINISHED',
                                     'CANCELED',
                                     'PICKED')
                           THEN
                               1
                           ELSE
                               0
                       END)
                 / COUNT (order_line_id)
                 * (  (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (
                                from_utc_timestamp (now (),
                                                    'MYRegion'))
                          - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                       / 60)
                    / (  (  UNIX_TIMESTAMP (lat)
                          - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (eat))
                       / 60))
                     AS ratio
            FROM (SELECT delivery_slot_from_hour,
                         order_line_id,
                         order_line_status,
                         eat,
                         lat
                    FROM my_table
                   WHERE SUBSTR (delivery_slot_from_hour, 1, 10) =
                         '2023-06-28') subquery
        GROUP BY delivery_slot_from_hour, eat, lat) main
GROUP BY main.delivery_slot_from_hour,
         main.ratio,
         main.order_lines,
         main.order_lines_finished
ORDER BY delivery_slot_from;
```

Is there a way how to fix this and get the output grouped by only 'delivery_slot_from'?

Comment: You are selecting columns you are neither aggregating or grouping by.

Comment: @Stu how should your comment help me? How can I rewrite it, so that the output is grouped only by the one column?

Comment: The only way to get this to work is to use aggregate functions on all the columns that aren't in the GROUP BY. If you don't do that then what are you expecting in the columns that are neither aggregated or in the group by? Presumably there could be multiple values/rows being aggregated into a single group by row so you need to define in your SQL which/what value is going to be used

Comment: @BiSaM You must aggregate eg sum, min, max avg etc any column (or derived column referencing a non-aggregated column) or pre-aggregate rows from tables before joining if applicable.